# How to convert this class component to functional component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this class component and i want to convert it in a functional component, how can I do? I tried to do it but i have some issue whit the this.chart properties in the `componentDidMount()` method, where i have to put it in functional component? I also tried to use the hook `useRef()` in the place of `createRef()` is it correct? Anyone can provide me a full converted example so i can understand how to do it? Thank you

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import OrgChart from '@balkangraph/orgchart.js';

export default class Chart extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.divRef = React.createRef();
  }

  shouldComponentUpdate() {
    return false;
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.chart = new OrgChart(this.divRef.current, {
      nodes: this.props.nodes,

      nodeBinding: {
        field_0: 'name',
        img_0: 'img',
      },
    });

    this.chart.on('init', function () {
      console.log('init');
    });

    this.chart.on('click', function () {
      console.log('click');
    });
  }

  render() {
    return <div id="tree" ref={this.divRef}></div>;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not that much different really.

The main thing is the use of the `React.useEffect`..

Also note, in your above your not doing anything with chart on component unmount, if you return a function from `useEffect` you can use that to cleanup on unmount. Also note the need for `this` is now gone..

Below is your code converted. E&OE

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import OrgChart from '@balkangraph/orgchart.js';

export default function Chart(props) {
  const divRef = React.createRef();
  useEffect(() => {
    const chart = new OrgChart(divRef.current, {
      nodes: props.nodes,
      nodeBinding: {
        field_0: 'name',
        img_0: 'img',
      },
    });

    chart.on('init', function () {
      console.log('init');
    });

    chart.on('click', function () {
      console.log('click');
    });

  }, []);
  return <div id="tree" ref={divRef}></div>
}
```

As pointed out above your current code is not doing anything about unmounting the component, often things like chart components have a destroy method etc, looking at the docs for OrgCharts if it's the same -> https://balkan.app/OrgChartJS/API/classes/OrgChart#destroy

So to really finish the component off,.  I would put this in the `useEffect` hook

```
useEffect(() => {
  const chart = ....
  ....
  return () => {
    chart.destroy();
  }
},[]);
```

Comment: Is the same if I use createRef() or the hook useRef() ? i also need to update the chart content each time the nodes props change, but in the offical documentation: https://balkan.app/OrgChartJS/Docs/React it seems they suggest to avoid this: shouldComponentUpdate() { return false; }

Comment: so I thought about using another useEffect, like this: useEffect(() => { chart.load(nodes) },[nodes]} but chart in your solution is declared inside the first useEffect, and if I try to make it external i have this error: "Assignments to the 'chart' variable from inside React Hook useEffect will be lost after each render."

Comment: @Trispo  Another `useEffect` will do nothing here to help.  If you want to update on nodes changing without recreating the chart, one idea is use `React.memo`, and forward refs.

Comment: @Trispo  If your wanting to a way to update chart with nodes changing, without mount / remount of a chart component.   That might be worth another question, as updating here would make the question / answer a fair bit larger and further away from your initial question.

Answer (score 2):

```js
import React, { useEffect, useRef } from 'react';
import OrgChart from '@balkangraph/orgchart.js';

function Chart({ nodes }) {
  const divRef = useRef();
  let chart = null;

  useEffect(() => {
    chart = new OrgChart(divRef.current, {
      nodes: nodes,
      nodeBinding: {
        field_0: 'name',
        img_0: 'img',
      },
    });

    chart.on('init', function () {
      console.log('init');
    });

    chart.on('click', function () {
      console.log('click');
    });

    return () => {
      // Cleanup when the component unmounts
      if (chart) {
        chart.destroy();
      }
    };
  }, [nodes]);

  return <div id="tree" ref={divRef}></div>;
}

export default Chart;
```

Comment: Your effect dependency on nodes is a good idea, but for some reason the OP specifically wants to prevent that -> `shouldComponentUpdate() { return false; }`

Comment: I don't even know the reason but the official documentation (class component) suggests doing this -> https://balkan.app/OrgChartJS/Docs/React

Comment: Passing nodes as a dependency to useEffect, with each change of the props the component would execute a new OrgChart() each time. 

Wouldn't it be better to create a new useEffect?

useEffect(() => {
  chart.load(nodes)
},[nodes]}

but there is another problem, if i try to declare char outiside the first useEffect, like in the above reply i have the following error -> "Assignments to the 'chart' variable from inside React Hook useEffect will be lost after each render."